# Overload ignored inside generic function

Tags: vb.net, generics, types

When I run the following type check code, it produces the result:

```
True
False
```

Why is this?

```vb
Module VBModule

    Class TypeKey(Of T)
        Public Sub New()

        End Sub
        Public Shared Operator =(k0 As TypeKey(Of T), k1 As TypeKey(Of T)) As Boolean
            Return True
        End Operator
        Public Shared Operator <>(k0 As TypeKey(Of T), k1 As TypeKey(Of T)) As Boolean
            Return False
        End Operator
        Public Shared Operator =(k0 As TypeKey(Of T), k1 As Object) As Boolean
            Return False
        End Operator
        Public Shared Operator <>(k0 As TypeKey(Of T), k1 As Object) As Boolean
            Return True
        End Operator
    End Class
    
    Public Function is_same_type(Of U, V)() As Boolean
        Return New TypeKey(Of U)() = New TypeKey(Of V)()
    End Function
 
    Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine(New TypeKey(Of Integer)() = New TypeKey(Of Integer)())
        Console.WriteLine(is_same_type(Of Integer, Integer)())
    End Sub
  
End Module
```

When testing on an online [VBNET IDE](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_vb.net_online.php), there are no warnings.

Comment: Because `is_same_type(Of U, V)` is [compiled once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68136879/new-modifier-works-unexpectedly-inside-a-generic-method-call#comment120427309_68136879), not per each `U, V`. Hence it's compiled based on what is known about `U, V` at the time of compilation, which is that they are `object`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [`new` modifier works unexpectedly inside a generic method call \[duplicate\]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68136879/11683)

Comment: Perhaps you're used to C++ templates and are expecting generics to behave the same way?  If you want to check for type equality, there are ways of doing it using `Type`.  If you want `is_same_type` to work, then you can't use an `Operator` because they can't be generic (except in terms of the containing class) so you can't get one that works for two potentially different type parameters on `TypeKey`; you'll need to write a non-operator function instead.

Answer (score 0):

> there are no warnings

That's because you have another overload with an `Object` parameter. So, it falls back to that.

**Well, why does it fall back to the overload with the `Object` parameter, to begin with?**

That's because [Overload Resolution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/overload-resolution) is handled at compile-time, not run-time. During compile-time, the compiler knows nothing about your type `V`. It has no way of knowing that it's actually the same type as `U` *in this particular instance*. So, it *always* uses the overload with `Object`.

You can actually confirm this in two ways:

1. If you hover over the `=` operator, you can see that the overload that's being used is `=(k0 As TypeKey(Of U), k1 As Object)`:

   [image]
2. If you remove (or comment out) that overload, you get a compiler error with the following message:

   > Overload resolution failed because no accessible '=' can be called with these arguments:
   >
   > 'Public Shared Operator =(k0 As VBModule.TypeKey(Of U), k1 As VBModule.TypeKey(Of U)) As Boolean': Value of type 'VBModule.TypeKey(Of V)' cannot be converted to 'VBModule.TypeKey(Of U)'.

   **[Try it online](https://rextester.com/ZSSJT6884)**.

Comment: That is a very nice answer but i dont see a solution in it, if there is no solution could you please state as such.

Comment: @Vye A solution to what exactly? You didn't specify the actual requirements of what you're trying to do. Your question was simply "why does my code behave like this?". To provide a solution, we need to know what your end goal is. Are you just trying to make `Dim isEqual = New TypeKey(Of SomeType1)() = New TypeKey(Of SomeType2)()` more concise? Do you actually want the `=` operator to _always_ return true for any two `TypeKey` objects regardless of the generic type arguments or was the `Return True` just a placeholder?

Comment: It might be better to post this as a new question. I can't say for sure until you describe the requirements. I might edit the answer to address them if the original question isn't changed drastically.

Comment: @4168d6564 I am looking for a solution that allows generic functions to use overloaded operators correctly; and as for what I am trying to use it for `is_same_type(Of U, V)()` should explain that in its name.

Comment: @Vye They _are_ using overloaded operators/methods correctly. They might not be doing what you had expected but they're doing what they're supposed to do as explained above. Are you sure this isn't an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/)? With the current information you provided, I don't think I (or anyone) can suggest a solution. I asked you several questions in my previous comment but you seem to have ignored most of them. Based on how you answer them, I might be able to propose a solution for the _actual_ problem that you're trying to solve.